# Генерация случайной строки

Tags: java

Из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117328/how-can-i-generate-random-strings-in-java):

```
new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
```

Результатом будет строка из случайных букв-цифр длиной 26 символов.

Мне понятно почему 32, что это за число. Но я никак не могу понять почему именно 130. Как это число влияет на результат, на конечную длину строки.
Пожалуйста, объяснить в чём же связь.

Comment: numBits(130) - максимальная длина в битах нового BigInteger.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20java.util.Random)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используется конструктор BigInteger с указанием максимальной длины случайного числа в битах.

130 бит соответствует 26 цифрам при использовании toString(32), т.к. каждые 5 бит преобразуются в одну цифру (2^5=32)

При использовании другого основания (radix) вместо 32 нужно учитывать количество требуемых битов - двоичный логарифм основания.

```
bits_per_digit = ln(radix) / ln(2)
```

Например, на каждую цифру по основанию 36 требуется 5.17 бит. Умножаем 5.17 на число цифр, округляем вверх. Для 26 цифр это будет 135 бит.

Comment: Хорошо. 32 = 2^5. 130 / 5 = 26. Всё кратно. Понятно. А если toString(36), то как тут тогда правильно рассчитывается определенное число для определенной длины?

Comment: На каждую цифру по основанию 36 требуется 5.17 бит. Умножаем 5.17 на число цифр, округляем вверх. Например, для 26 цифр это будет 135 бит.